# React js application ensuring authentication

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am working on a react js application using redux. The router is implemented using injectors. How can authentication be ensured. If a user directly navigates to a page using url, a check must be performed to see if he has logged in.Code below

```
export default function createRoutes(store) {
// Create reusable async injectors using getAsyncInjectors factory
   const { injectReducer, injectSagas } = getAsyncInjectors(store); 

  return [
  {
  path: '/',
  name: 'login',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    const importModules = Promise.all([
      System.import('Controller/LoginViewController'),
      System.import('Controller/LoginViewController/reducer'),
      System.import('Controller/LoginViewController/sagas'),
     ]);
    const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);
    importModules.then(([component,loginReducer,loginSagas]) => {
      injectReducer('loginViewController',loginReducer.default);
      injectSagas('loginViewController',loginSagas.default);          
      renderRoute(component);

    });

    importModules.catch(errorLoading);
  }
}
```

Comment: I generally have an interceptor in the Request pipeline so that when any requests have been rejected with a 401 then push them straight to `/login` or something. This can be easily down by encapsulating the `<Route>` component by making your own `<EnsureAuthenticatedRoute>` ... see the Router docs they have example

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link